How to translate Flutter app using api translation service(i.e, Google) in backend
I am recently working on flutter app in which I need to implement translation in whole app  I  decided to use googleapi so I  need your help to get a detailed procedure about how to implement google api translation for dynamic data i.e, backend api data and here I need to add  multiple language support (i.e tamil,hindi,malayalam,telugu)
I  have done the static translation using [flutter_localization]
(https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_localization) but now I need to translate the whole app even the datas from api Waiting for your answers Thanks in advance !
